# Responsive sub menu box

Tags: html, css

I'm working on navigation bar and I got a problem that is responsive related.

[image: This]

I want the sub menu box to keep inside the content always. I must not go to the grey area. Is there a way to do this? I would prefer to keep the size of the sub menu box

This is my code:(I'm using Umbraco)

HTML:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{ var home = CurrentPage.Site(); }

@if (home.Children.Any())
{
    @* Get the first page in the children *@
    var naviLevel = home.Children.First().Level;

    @* Add in level for a CSS hook *@
    <div class="linje"></div>
    <ul class="meny level-@naviLevel">
        @* For each child page under the home node *@
        @foreach (var childPage in home.Children)
{

    if (childPage.Children.Any())
    {

        <li class="dropdown has-child @(childPage.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
            @if (childPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "Huvudmeny")
            {
                <span>@childPage.Name</span>
                @childPages(childPage.Children)
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="@childPage.Url" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@childPage.Name</a>
            }
            @helper childPages(dynamic pages)
{
            @* Ensure that we have a collection of pages *@

    if (pages.Any())
    {
        @* Get the first page in pages and get the level *@
        var naviLevel = pages.First().Level;

        @* Add in level for a CSS hook *@

    <ul class="meny dropdown-menu sublevel level-@(naviLevel)">
        @foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>

                @* if the current page has any children *@
                @if (page.Children.Any())
                {
                    @* Call our helper to display the children *@
                    @childPages(page.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

    }

}

        </li>

    }

    else
    {
                <li class="@(childPage.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
                    <a href="@childPage.Url">@childPage.Name</a>
                </li>
            }   
        }
    </ul>
        <div class="linje col-md-12" ></div>

}
```

CSS:

```
nav .has-child:hover > .sublevel {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu>li { float: left; width: 50% !important; }
ul.dropdown-menu{
    width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Its the width of those sub menus that must be affecting. If you still want to keep that width for all sub menu's other than last, then you can use :first and :last css property to solve your issue.

Comment: I tired it but it doesn't work. I think it has to do with umbraco

Comment: A. It will be better if you can add the output html (Not server code). B. Please add the `css` code of `nav .has-child > .sublevel` (not the `:hover` state but the regular).